# Serving images with JavaScript on a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm trying to find different ways to serve images on a web site.

The most straight forward is obviously to use the `<img>` tag.

What other methods exist?

I like the way images are served [here](http://www.kvraudio.com/get/1690.html):

> When a user clicks on the image, a larger version is presented and the surrounding screen darkens. There are also 'next image' and 'previous image' buttons in the top corners of the image.

Does anyone know how it is done and where I can find out more?

Comment: do you mean the &lt;img> tag>

Comment: more or less, all implementations use <img /> tag. They only differ in how the image is presented & also when the image is loaded..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple examples of lightboxes using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) are:

- http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/
- http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 1):

It is called Lightbox generally, there are many alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

it's also called modal window and here is [some](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/05/27/modal-windows-in-modern-web-design/)